# moment - Issue with fromNow

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hey I'm trying to calculate user age using Moment.

```
function getAge(birthDate) {
  const start = moment(birthDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
  const end = moment();
  return start.to(end, true);
}
```

Before the month of may, the result is 1 year over:

```
getAge("1989-01-01"); // 31 years
getAge("1989-05-01"); // 30 years
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tesla-bzb3d

the behavior is the same using `fromNow` instead of `to`

do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: it is because it is rounded to the closest integer year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `.to()` is a relative time string and it internally rounds the values in either direction (so 29.5 years would become 30 years). It is meant for display purposes like showing "posted 3 minutes ago" in forum or blog posts.

You are looking for the `.diff()` method that calculates the difference, but will only account for full units of measurement provided by the second argument, i.e. truncating the actual number.

```
  const start = moment(birthDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
  age = moment().diff(start, "years");
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lewin-e6vrt

Answer (score -1):

You may use `diff` function like:

```
function getAge(birthDate) {
  const start = moment(birthDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
  const end = moment();
  return end.diff(start, 'years');
}

console.log(getAge("1989-01-01"));
console.log(getAge("1989-05-01"));
```